# PHP timezone issue | UTC and GMT

Tags: php, time, timezone

I have a developed a application which store the user post created time in  database. In DB its stored in UTC time then converted to user's timezone for presentation time.

My issue is time different from actual time . Its showing 13 minutes ahead.
i just run a piece code in that server its shows 13 minutes ahead.
Server location is Canada

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
echo date('d-m-Y H:i');
```

Every time its shows 13 minutes difference.

Comment: is the time on your server correct?

Comment: Thanks for you reply. Server time is not correct , its 13 minute ahead

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct that this issue can be marked as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always take a look at your timezone configuration on your server. In relation to server sided programming/scripting it will always use your local time/date.

If you are in a wrong timezone you need to chance the ntp servers on your system.